# Google Eclipse plugin warnings about test dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, google-eclipse-plugin

I created a new Web App project in Eclipse (via the Google plugin) and began adding JARs to the `war/WEB-INF/lib` folder. However, there are several test-only dependencies (`junit`, `mockito`, `arquillian`, `hamcrest`, etc.) that I do not want to pacakge in the product WAR. So instead, I just created a `lib/test` directory under my project root, added the test JARs there, and then added them to the project buildpath.

When I do this, I get the following Eclipse Warning (in this example, for `mockito`):

> The following classpath entry '/home/myuser/workbench/eclipse/workspace/myapp/lib/test/mockito-1.9.5.jar' will not be available on the server's classpath.

If I put these JARs inside `war/WEB-INF/lib`, they go away; but I don't want them in there. Is there a way to tell the Google Eclipse plugin to ignore these dependencies because they are *test* dependencies? Otherwise, how do GWT developers normally quiet these warnings? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on a warning, Quick Fix, "Do not warn me...".